# Arithmetic operators in drools

Tags: constraints, drools, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to implement a rule in Drools language. I need to add up two integer values from two variables. I have tried some different ways but none of them seem to work. I get either failure due to the "+" symbol or due to the "eval" function. I need to do the summation and then compare its value to another one for the rule to fire. These are the combinations I have already tried

```
     $generationGrain : ($smallerGenerationIndex.intValue() + App.GENERATION_TIME.intValue() ) 
    
     $generationGrain : $smallerGenerationIndex.intValue() + App.GENERATION_TIME.intValue()
 
     $generationGrain : eval($smallerGenerationIndex.intValue() + App.GENERATION_TIME.intValue())
     
     $generationGrain : eval($smallerGenerationIndex + App.GENERATION_TIME)
    
     $generationGrain : ($smallerGenerationIndex + App.GENERATION_TIME )  
    
     $generationGrain : ($smallerGenerationIndex.intValue() + App.GENERATION_TIME.intValue() )
```

Is it just not possible to do it or am I missing something? Should I just create an rule with the summation after the `then` and then another rule with the conditional and the other value?

Answer (score 1):

Integer has a [static sum operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-) you could use in this case.

```
$generationGrain: Integer() from Integer.sum( $smallerGenerationIndex, App.GENERATION_TIME )
```

That would also let you apply constraints. For example, if you wanted to write a rule such that it would only trigger if the sum is negative, you could do like:

```
$generationGrain: Integer(this < 0) from ...
```

Alternatively if you wanted to sum up values across a list of objects, you could use an [`accumulate`](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-WHEN-elements-ref_drl-rules) with a `sum` function. But for two discrete numbers I'd do it like this.

(The other numeric wrapper types also have similar functions, eg. Double.)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reuse and give business name to some computation. DSL would be suitable here

```
[when]SmallerGenerationIndex = $smallerGenerationIndex.intValue()
[when]GenerationTime = App.GENERATION_TIME.intValue()
[when]GenerationGrain = (SmallerGenerationIndex + GenerationTime)
```

Now in rules you can reuse value with clear business meaning, it will be resolved to longer expressions each time, but this technical stuff would be hidden from human eyes.